# Should RandomAccessIterators mutate themselves on call to idx()?

Tags: rust

The trait RandomAccessIterator defines the following function:

```
fn idx(&mut self, index: uint) -> Option<A>;
```

Since self is mutable, I would expect a call to idx() to mutate the iterator, e.g. `it.idx(3)` would advance the iterator three elements. However, that's not what the `slice::Items` implementation currently does; `it.idx(3)` gives the third element from the current element, but does not advance or mutate the iterator.

So my question is: should iterators implementing RandomAccessIterator mutate themselves in a call to idx()? And if not, why does the function require a mutable reference to self?

Comment: Well, no one forces you to write mutating code. If you can get away without it, fine, but if you can't, you still have the possibility to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it shouldn't advance with `.idx`. The method uses `&mut self` just like other iterator methods, for [reasons outlined here.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/f4083a22451692b9ae360f3d12bfb8cb52b096e4) In short, it's to allow you to call closure fields in the iterator struct.